# Пропускается анимация выезда кастомного кард вью

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Мне нужно было сделать подобное (не обращайте внимание на лейауты я убрал лого):

[карточка логина](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu1d1.png)

При клике "Sign up" карточка логина должна съезжать вниз и карточки регистрации должны выезжать из под экрана:

[карточки регистрации](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddCrQ.png)

3 карточки (все карточки это кастомные View) все карточки имеют похожие лейауты и каждая при клике на "Continue" должна съезжать вниз

**Проблема**

Анимация выезда карточек регистрации после анимации карточки логина пропускается. Карточка логина съезжает без проблем но потом начинается пауза примерно ~1 секунду и карточки регистрации пропускают анимацию выезда и просто появляются на экране. Анимация съезжания карточек регистрации работает без проблем.

**Вопрос**

Как решить проблему с пропуском анимации выезда карточек регистрации?

**Код**

Класс родитель для всех карточек:

```
public abstract class CardStackView extends RelativeLayout {

protected CardStackListener cardStackListener;

public CardStackView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CardStackView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CardStackView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public void setCardStackListener(CardStackListener cardStackListener) {
    this.cardStackListener = cardStackListener;
    cardStackListener.onCreated(this);
}

protected interface CardStackListener {
    void onCreated(CardStackView view);

    void onRemove();

    void onAdd();
}

public abstract void setShade(float value);

public abstract void enable();

public abstract void disable();
```

}

Этот класс отвечает за переключение между карточками:

```
public class CardStackFragmentView extends FrameLayout {

private static final int MARGIN = 10;
private static final float SCALE = .1f;
private static final float ALPHA = .1f;

private List<CardStackView> totalCards = new LinkedList<>();
private List<CardStackView> cards = new LinkedList<>();
private Handler cardHandler = new Handler();

public CardStackFragmentView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "CardStackFragmentView");
}

public CardStackFragmentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "CardStackFragmentView");
}

/**
 * Adds cards from params to this card holder
 * and adds proper sizes and shade to be viewed like a card stack
 * @param cardStackViews cards for this card holder
 */
public void addCards(CardStackView... cardStackViews) {
    totalCards.addAll(Arrays.asList(cardStackViews));
    cards.addAll(Arrays.asList(cardStackViews));
    for (int i = cards.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        CardStackView card = cards.get(i);
        int offset = i;
        if (i == 0) {
            card.enable();
        } else {
            card.disable();
        }
        card.setCardStackListener(new CardStackView.CardStackListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCreated(CardStackView view) {
                view.animate()
                        .scaleX(1 - SCALE * offset)
                        .translationY(-MARGIN * offset);
                view.setShade(ALPHA * offset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRemove() {
                removeFromTop();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdd() {
                addCardToTop();
            }

        });
    }

    //I thought may be if i ll add cards in different threads it solves the problem

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        int tmp = i;
        cardHandler.postDelayed(() -> addView(cards.get((cards.size() - 1 - tmp))), i * 20);
    }
}


/**
 * Adds card on top of stack and reanimates all cards in stack
 */
public void addCardToTop() {
    CardStackView fragment = totalCards.get(totalCards.size() - (cards.size() + 1));
    fragment.animate().translationY(-(fragment.getHeight() + 30));
    cards.add(0, fragment);
    fragment.enable();
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        CardStackView card = cards.get(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            card.enable();
        } else {
            card.disable();
        }
        card.animate()
                .scaleX(1 - SCALE * i)
                .translationY(-MARGIN * i);
        card.setShade(ALPHA * i);
    }
}

public void removeFromTop() {
    Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "removeFromTop");
    CardStackView fragment = cards.get(0);
    fragment.animate().translationY(fragment.getHeight() + 30);
    fragment.disable();
    cards.remove(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        CardStackView card = cards.get(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            card.enable();
        } else {
            card.disable();
        }
        card.animate()
                .scaleX(1 - SCALE * i)
                .translationY(-MARGIN * i);
        card.setShade(ALPHA * i);
    }
}
```

}

Он клик метод который начинает анимацию:

```
@OnClick(R.id.tv_login_register)
public void createAccountClicked(View view) {
    LoginActivity loginActivity = ((LoginActivity) getContext());
    RegisterCard registerCard = new RegisterCard(loginActivity);
    loginActivity.hideMenu();
    view.setEnabled(false);
    startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(loginActivity, R.anim.move_out));
    new Handler().postDelayed(
            () -> {
                loginActivity.getCardsRelativeLayout().removeView(LoginCard.this);
                loginActivity.getCardsRelativeLayout().addView(registerCard);
                registerCard.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(loginActivity, R.anim.move_in));
            },
            400);
}
```

Спасибо за ваше время. Надtюсь это поможет вам помочь мне)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была не в кастомной вьюхе, а в активити в которой она была (анимация не пропускалась это был просто большой фриз). Лейаут активити был слишком массивный и с огромной вложенностью. Так что я сделал его как можно легче и фризы исчезли. Вывод: **делайте ваши хмл лейауты как можно легче**. Простой ответ на мою "непростую" проблему.